# Failed to deploy a simple Node.js application on Microsoft Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, socket.io, azure-cloud-services

I was following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-nodejs-chat-app-socketio/) tutorial on deploying a Node.js chat application using Socket.IO onto Azure Cloud Service. Instead of using the chat example provided in the tutorial, I wrote my own with some improvements and other features, but the overall structure is basically the same.

Everything worked fine, I also tested my app using the emulator and it worked as expected. However, I just can't seem to publish it on the Azure service correctly.

I entered the following cmdlet:

```
Publish-AzureServiceProject -ServiceName mychatapp0323 -Location "East US" -Launch
```

And below are the messages I get:

```
PS C:\node\chatapp\WorkerRole1> Publish-AzureServiceProject -ServiceName mychatapp0323 -Location "East US" -Launch
WARNING: Publishing mychatapp0323 to Microsoft Azure. This may take several minutes...
WARNING: 12:02:17 AM - Preparing runtime deployment for service 'mychatapp0323'
WARNING: 12:02:17 AM - Verifying storage account 'mychatapp0323'...
WARNING: 12:02:52 AM - Preparing deployment for mychatapp0323 with Subscription ID:
0xxxxx8-xxx2-4xxe-8xx8-8xxx67xxxxx0...
WARNING: 12:04:22 AM - Connecting...
WARNING: 12:04:24 AM - Creating...
WARNING: 12:04:26 AM - Created hosted service 'mychatapp0323'.
WARNING: 12:04:27 AM - Uploading Package to storage service mychatapp0323...
WARNING: 12:04:58 AM - Starting...
WARNING: 12:06:04 AM - Created Deployment ID: 13df765e37e840cdb54a998498ab1745.
WARNING: 12:06:04 AM - Initializing...
WARNING: 12:09:06 AM - Instance WorkerRole1_IN_0 of role WorkerRole1 is busy.
Publish-AzureServiceProject : An error occurred while sending the request.
At line:1 char:1
+ Publish-AzureServiceProject -ServiceName mychatapp0323 -Location "Eas ...
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Publish-AzureServiceProject], HttpRequestException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.CloudService.PublishAzureServiceProjectCommand
```

The error message didn't occur after at least 2 hours since I entered the cmdlet, and it stuck at this line for a very long time (more than an hour):

```
WARNING: 12:09:06 AM - Instance WorkerRole1_IN_0 of role WorkerRole1 is busy.
```

Any idea why this is happening? The chat app I wrote can be found [here](https://github.com/mike8411251995/test1/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took your app and built it on my local environment. It didn't work as expected. I think the following would raise your issue:

1) Please consider updating your `dependencies` npm modules to the latest version.

2) In your `server.js` file, you required `ip` and `mongodb` modules, but you have not included them in `dependencies` section.

So I changed your `dependencies` in `package.json` file to something like below, then it worked.

```
"dependencies": { 
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "jade": "^1.11.0",
    "nib": "^1.1.2",
    "socket.io": "^1.7.3",
    "stylus": "^0.54.5",
    "ip": "^1.1.5",
    "mongodb": "^2.2.25"
}
```

Comment: Yes, that did solve my problem. However, deploying it on Azure App Service _without_ alternating the `package.json` file as you suggested also worked for me. Weird.